# Clang tidy doesn't work for StaticConstantCase

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

I'm trying to use clang-tidy (10.0.0) to check the formatting on my file:

```
#include "blabla.h"

static const int status = 1000;
static const int STATUS_REPLY_TIMEOUT_MS = 100;

namespace foo {
```

The .clang-tidy file I'm using is:

```
Checks: '-*,readability-identifier-naming'
CheckOptions:
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.VariableCase,                          value: camelBack  }
  - { key: readability-identifier-naming.StaticConstantCase ,                   value: UPPER_CASE }
```

I get an error:

```
warning: invalid case style for variable 'STATUS_REPLY_TIMEOUT_MS' [readability-identifier-naming]
static const int STATUS_REPLY_TIMEOUT_MS = 100;
```

It seems like `STATUS_REPLY_TIMEOUT_MS` is recognized as a variable instead of a static constant... I tried removing the `VariableCase` line, to check if that superseded the `StaticConstantCase`, but then I get no errors (where I would expect one on `static const int status = 1000;`). Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StaticConstantCase` only applies to static local variables.

Use `GlobalConstantCase` for namespace-scope static variables.